# How to extract point normals from a .vtk file?

Tags: point, vtk

I use vtkGenericDataObjectReader class to read a .vtk file which contains only point locations and VTK_TETRA cells:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Unstructured Grid
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 19002 double
-0.150669 0.33708199999999999 -0.053355
0.240651 -0.40023399999999998 -0.183224
-0.15488199999999999 -0.54804799999999998 -0.210316
... the other points ...
CELLS 75753 378765
4  3472 3996 7922 9626
4  5182 6191 12063 12612
4  5555 2996 18404 18616
... the other cells ...
```

After successfully read the file, I failed to get the point normals by:

```
VTK_CREATE(vtkGenericDataObjectReader, reader);
reader->SetFileName(file.toStdString().c_str());
reader->Update();

Q_ASSERT(reader->IsFileUnstructuredGrid());

VTK_CREATE(vtkUnstructuredGrid, ug);
ug = vtkUnstructuredGrid::SafeDownCast(reader->GetOutput());
vtkDataArray* normals = ug->GetPointData()->GetArray("Normals");
//vtkDataArray* normals = ug->GetPointData()->GetNormals();

VTK_CREATE(vtkDataSetMapper, modelMapper);
modelMapper->SetInputData(ug);
modelActor->SetMapper(modelMapper);

// ...
```

because the normals got to be a zero pointer.

However, the final rendered lighting effect seems to be reasonable. So Here is my question: (1) How VTK compute point normals in order to get the correct light effect? (2) What should I do to get the point normals?

Answer (score 1):

VTK got an `vtkPolyDataNormals` algorithm class which allow you to process the normals from a polygonal mesh.

```
VTK_CREATE(vtkGenericDataObjectReader, reader);
reader->SetFileName(file.toStdString().c_str());

VTK_CREATE(vtkPolyDataNormals, norms)
norms->SetInputConnection (reader->GetOutputPort ());
// the output of the vtkPolyDataNormals instance is a PolyData with normals calculated

norms->Update()
VTK_CREATE(vtkDataSetMapper, modelMapper);
modelMapper->SetInputData( norms->GetOutput () );
```

> [vtkPolyDataNormals](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataNormals.html#details) is a filter that computes point and/or cell normals for a polygonal mesh.

In that case, the output PolyData must got a non-zero normals pointer.

Comment: In my case, the output of "reader" is of type vtkUnstructuredGrid, but a vtkPolyData is required for the input of "norms", so vtkPolyDataNormals doesn't work here.

Comment: I've just made an edit. `reader->GetOutputPort()`, with that solution you're using the vtk pipeline instead of using a temporary instance of mesh. Or do you must finish with a vtkUnstructuredGrid at the end ? vtkPolyDataNormals has an `SetInputData` method inherited from vtkPolyDataAlgorithm which can take any `vtkDataObject*`